# How to migrate data from production to develop but scramble sensitive data?

Tags: sql, .net, entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database

**Setup today**

We currently have two SQL databases in our setup:

- Production database
- Develop database

We keep the table structures updated using Entity Framework Code First migrations, which is great because it's in version control.

**Challenge: how to handle data.**

We have never migrated production data from production to develop, simply because we have a lot of sensitive data we don't want (or are even allowed because of less security) on our development database.

This includes:

- Private data on users
- Emails on customers and users

However, the PROD and TEST website has started to differ a lot in content and looks, which is a problem because our environments diverge a lot.

**What I am looking for an answer on:**

**My question**: How do you easily migrate data from production to develop, but "hide" sensitive data?

In my imagination I am looking for something that:

1. Every week automatically migrate data
2. Scramble some fields (ie. move some values around, remove/add some letters in some tables)

But I have no idea how this is usually done in a professional environment.

**Technology stack**

We use Azure Database, .NET / Visual Studio and Entity Framework as an ORM.

Comment: You could generate a script of the entire schema (if necessary), and then generate a script of the data, removing the sensitive tables. You can do this using SQL Server Management Studio or Visual Studio > Tools > Sql Server > Data Comparison

Comment: I would use a script which generates mock data on a clean DB. So you would have test user and test data. Can you tell the reason why you are taking prod data? or why you need to take prod data?

Comment: @wuerzelchen Good question. My main concern is PROD and DEV is starting to diverge in how the website look. Ie. we have a concept of "Leads" in our system, and we start to see bugs because it's difficult to see if a lead looks wrong by looking at mock data. So we would like to look at "real life looking like" data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was contracted to a Fortune 50 company's finance department for a while, and faced this issue.  We wrote a custom application which would connect to the production database, extract the data we needed to load into the development database, and selectively scramble certain fields.  We used production data as the source due to the nature of the...data 'scenarios' that users had generated in the production data, and we wanted to represent these interrelationships as closely as possible in the development environment.

For example, meaningful textual names of certain elements were obfuscated randomly against a large table of strings in a text file, and numeric data values were multiplied against a number randomly chosen from within a limited range that was meaningful for that field.  We did not obfuscate everything, but only those data elements that were considered sensitive.

Because these records required a certain level of data integrity against related records in other tables, we found that only a custom app would satisfy our needs.

In your situation (user names and email addresses) it would be relatively straightforward to set up some dummy data, from which an app could generate "fake" names and emails.

Comment: I do not think you think Obfuscation means what it really means. Obfuscation is reversible, and if your scrambling is reversible then why scramble it in the first place? What you really need to do is replace ID's and Names with truly randomly generated values.

Comment: @ChrisPietschmann Tell that to [these researchers here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3437651_Data_obfuscation_Anonymity_and_desensitization_of_usable_data_sets) who describe data obfuscation techniques that we used.

Comment: Yeah, the industry overall has serious issues when it comes to Security. I've seen the word Obfuscation used all over the place. It may be a futile argument, but to me Obfuscation is security through obscurity which is no security at all.

Comment: My real takeaway here is it doesn't sound like it's an "2 hour task" and a default checkbox I just missed in SQL server :-) I think the solution makes sense, just much more custom and time consuming than I hoped for

Comment: @ChrisPietschmann obfuscate is just a word that existed before computers, and it means to make unclear or difficult to see/read/understand.

Comment: @htafoya Yeah, that's exactly what security through obscurity is. Obfuscation makes the code/data unclear or difficult to see/read/understand. While encryption make it impossible to see/read/understand without the correct algorithm to reverse the process. They are different things.